# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '<module_name>'

Tags: python, docker, setuptools

I have 2 projects in Python-

1. Framework (Python package)
2. App (Flask app)

The Framework project has a setup.py script using setuptools and I am importing the framework modules in the App project.

I installed the Framework package locally on my machine and app is able to find my framework package.

I am now trying to get the App running inside docker. I am using the following dockerfile -

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /app

COPY App /app/App
COPY Framework /app/Framework
COPY requirements.txt /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN python Framework/setup.py install

ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]

CMD ["App/application.py"]
```

Folder structure of the code

```
Project
|
|___ Framework
|    |
|    |__framework-subfolder>code.py
|    |
|    |__setup.py
|
|___ App
|    |
|    |__app-subfolder>app.py
|
|___ Dockerfile
```

app.py is referencing code.py.

code.py file -

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

def create_app(name):
    return Flask(name)

def create_api(app):
    return Api(app)
```

app.py file -

```
from framework-subfolder.code import create_api, create_app
...
...
```

When I run docker build, it completes successfully but when I call docker run, I get the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'framework-subfolder'
```

I am a little lost as to what I am missing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: We would need to see more to be able to help. For a start: how do the `Framework/setup.py` and `App/application.py` files, as well as the directory tree of `Framework` look like?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have updated the folder structure in the original question.

Comment: Quite difficult to know for sure with so little details, but I can't see anything in here showing that there is indeed a `Framework` Python module. [mcve]

Comment: Thanks again. I have added lot more details and a part of the code in the question. Let me know if I can give more details. Sorry I am new to stack overflow and learning the process.

Comment: I will assume these are still not the actual names, since I don't believe `framework-subfolder` is a valid Python identifier, and thus the issue is not reproducible. I understand one does not necessarily want to show their actual own code, but you'd do yourself a great favor if you could actually simplify down your own issue to a [mcve]. At best you'd find out yourself the cause of your issue, at worst it'd facilitate the work for others trying to help you.